# jQuery and cross domain with jsonp - please help

Tags: asp.net, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I am trying out jsonp with jQuery. I found many examples on the web and I believe my code is correct, but its still not working for me.

My web service:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace App_Code
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", Name = "WebService")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [ScriptService]
    public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string GetAd()
        {
            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                Prop1 = "some property",
            });
            string callback = HttpContext.Current.Request["callback"];
            return string.Format("{0}({1})", callback, json);
        }
    }
}
```

Client-side:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('Loading...');

    $.ajax({ url: 'http://mediaserver/WebService.asmx/GetAd?callback?',
        data: {},
        success: function (json) {
            alert(json);
        }
    });
});
```

Firebug shows this is a success, but I am getting null from the alert. I have my webservice in iis7 locally and I am testing through my debug in my client project.

I need to get cross-domain working.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two question marks in your url `http://mediaserver/WebService.asmx/GetAd?callback?`

My thoughts would be that it needs to be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('Loading...');

    $.ajax({ url: 'http://mediaserver/WebService.asmx/GetAd?callback=',
        data: {},
        success: function (json) {
            alert(json);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The 2 ? are probably ok, the GetAd is kinda servlet mapping I guess. The missing = was (is) his problem I guess

Comment: haha, you edited as I commented. Now my comment looks out of context.

Comment: This is missunderstanding. I think the = should be there, see my answer. I just explained the 2 questionmarks are ok. It't like search.php?callback=?, completely valid. But in his question he doesn't have the = and that caused the problem (I think)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `=` in the URL. The `callback` should have the `=` (at least it works like this for me). First line would be:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://mediaserver/WebService.asmx/GetAd?callback=?'
...
```

Also you are not specifying you want JSON, either use `dataType: 'json'` in the ajax request or go directly with `$.getJSON` ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)). Not sure of jQuery is capable of autodetecting JSONP. This might not be causing the bug though.

Comment: I tried     $.getJSON('http://mediaserver/WebService.asmx/GetAd?callback=?',
    function (data) {
        alert('test' data);
    });

Comment: Did it work? Also have a look on the response in firebug. Does it have the right format?